# Java & Mysql processing massive data

Tags: java, mysql, large-data

My problem is, I have two database tables, one with around 10 000 records, and other with 5 000 000 records, with 56 columns each record. Now what I have to do, compare each record from that 10 000 with every record from the other table, and find 10 best ( compare columns values etc).
So Im looking for some idea how to to this in a reasonable amount of time, becuase as of now it would take me way too long...
I have been looking over the internet and found hadoop for instance, however I have never used it and I'm not sure if it would do the job in my case...
My machine has 2 cores and 4gb ram so its not a bull.
Thanks for any answers if it is even doable in a reasonable amount of time

Comment: I would start by putting those 10,000 records into memory (if you can) and then iterating over the 5 mil.

Comment: it's unclear to me why compare each one; sort them first and compare only first rows...

Comment: Reasonable is not one week or so.
Shawn- so store 10 000 in lets say ArrayList and then take one by one from the database and compare?
user1121883- wouldn't work for my sorting and taking just first rows, have to compare each one

Comment: How do you define better? Is it a transitive relation, i.e. x "better than" y AND y "better than" z => x "better than" z. If it's the case, you don't need to compare each item with another one

Comment: I have to calculate euklides distance between them, thats why I have to compare with every record from the 5000 000

Comment: @user2141889 i am assuming that you are calculating euclidian distance for how far each item is closer to other. Normally these are used in item based collaborative filtering and they are calculated offline. So speed of calculation does not matter if calculation is not spanning more than 3-4 hours.

Comment: @Trying yes, the point is from what I have been trying it would take more than days not hours to complete thats why I'm looking for some solution

Comment: @user2141889 if it is taking so much time you should upgrade your mysql version, box and fine tune mysql, so that it will process faster. I have seen calculation for 10 million it does not take days to finish.

Comment: @Trying Thanks for the answer gonna look for some mysql box and tuning. I'm thinking about some indexex however I'm not sure if they are gonna do anything in my case where I just select * from

Comment: @user2141889 can you rephrase your question so that i can post what are the things you can look for fine tuning.

Comment: Well I have two tables in my MySql database, as of now, I am loading the first table, 10 000 records into memory with my java code, that works just fine, 300 miliseconds or so. Now I have to find top 15 euclides distance result from the second table (5 000 000) records for every record from the first, So it's gonna be 10 000 x 15 records after computation.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of hadoop is that it can help you to parallelize code execution. If you have only one machine I don't think that hadoop is suitable for you. Since you have 2 cores you may take advantage of Java threads.

Another limitation factor is memory. Basicaly if you can fetch all records into memory just do it before you starts the computations. If it's not the case (seems that db size exceeds your RAM size) helper thread can fetch additional records from database into memory as soon as computation threads have finished with some records. Below is the algorithm sketch:

- Two Worker threads would work in parallel (num of threads = num of cpus because of compute intensive task)
- FirstArray = Load 10.000 in the array or ArrayList, make sure that you're not using concurrent structures. Both threads would access this array, however would not mutate it. SecondArray would be delivered by DB Thread (points 3-4). FirstArray would be the same for both threads, SecondArray would be different. You would have nested loops:

  ```
  for (elem1: FirstArray) {
      for (elem2: SecondArray){
           computeSmth(elem1, elem2)
           if (bestSoFar()) store()
      }
  }
  ```

As soon as Worker thread is done it asks BlockingQueue for the next portion of data - that is new SecondArray.

- DB Thread (actually third thread) would be responsible for fetching data from the database in batches and populating arrays that would be further processesed by Worker Threads.
- Suppose 400.000 elements from the second table fits into memory. Let's split it into 4 regions.

  - 1 region would be used for the elements being processed by the first thread,
  - 2 region would be used for elements beeing processed by the second thread,
  - 3 region is an array that waits to be taken by one of the threads in BlockingQueue (with capacity of 1),
  - 4 would be used for the data that is fetched from the database, but could not be put to the queue, because another array is not taken by one of the worker threads. This basically means
    that DB Thread would block until some thread takes next array from the queue, this means that it's done with previous array and previous array could be GCed, that means
    that you would not run out of memory.
- Queue size might be a subject for tuning based on maximum MySQL batch size, MySQL retrieval time and time spent on one batch processing by Worker thread.
- The logic of bestSoFar() should be well-thought to minimize thread synchronization.
- Basically the algorithm should scale well (each CPU may give near linear improvement).

Comment: Multithreading could give you sufficient performance boost if you have enough cores, time spent on (implementation of multithreaded version - implementation of single threaded version) might exceed (single threaded application execution time - multithreaded application execution time). This matters if it's one-shot task and the code would not be reused

Comment: Thank you for your answer it has pointed me in the right direction I think.

Answer (score 0):

There are a dozen ways to do it. It depends a bit on the what you need to compare.

A way to select the rows from both tables that have the same value for the most important column. Than do a compare for each matching rows from both tables.

But, if the matching is straight forwared (a column matches completly or not), I would write a good SQL query that returns the number of matching columns for each row combination and select the top 10 :).

The best strategy is, i think, to process the 10.000 rows 1-by-1 and try to find the best matching rows with a query and do an aditional calculation in java to sort the best one.

Ideally, i would write an MapReduce job for it. But if you don't have it setup already, hard programming is your best other option.

Comment: I have to calculate euclides distance between record from first table and records from the second, take 15 best, thats why I think i really have to go through all the records.

Comment: I do not now much about that calculation, but I bet you can do part of it with SQL and make a preselection. Otherwise, make a join product of both tables and process them row by row and keep the best 10 matches in memory. I assume you want the best 10 for each of the 10.000 rows.

Answer (score 0):

5 million x 57 doubles is somewhere like 2 GB of RAM.

Should not be a problem with the 4 GB you have.

To make things faster, use indexes. Maybe implement your own indexes, too.

Or use **sorting** where appropriate.